# Writing/Updating a .INI file to a relative path and reading back from the path using WriteProfileBinary() or WriteProfileInt()

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I've got this legacy code writing to a default location in windows directory(using WriteProfileInt & WriteProfileBinary). In order for the application not to require Admin privileges I would like to write the INI files to a different location.

This is what I've done so far:

All string parameters are handled(Using WritePrivateProfileString). However, I cannot seem to find similar functions in MSDN for writing integer or Binary which accepts writing to relative paths. I've done some type casting to handle the integer params. But would like to know if anyone has a better way/idea of handling the Integers/Binary params

Comment: There is no such winapi function, CWinApp::WriteProfileBinary is an MFC helper function.  It converts the bytes to a string, then writes that string with a winapi function.  Just copy the code, vc/atlmfc/src/mfc/appui3.cpp.  Or just ditch it, ini files are quite horrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WritePrivateProfileStruct function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and then  GetPrivateProfileStruct) like that:

```
struct S
{
    int i;
    int j;
    S() : i(1), j(2) {}
} Struct;
BOOL b = WritePrivateProfileStruct(
    L"lpszSection",
    L"lpszKey",
    &Struct,
    sizeof Struct,
    L"d:\\test.ini");
```

Comment: pls do you by any chance also know if mfc provides something to write to a relative path so that I can bypass using this line (CFrameWnd::SaveBarState(sProfile);) which writes  to C:\Windows?

Comment: You may need to change `CWinApp::m_pszProfileName` - see MSDN for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xykfyy20.aspx